# How can I calculate $(1+i)^{5404}$?

Tags: complex-numbers

I saw a pattern while evaluating some other powers of similar complex number so I tried to calculate the above question by expanding it, please tell me if it is correct...?

$(1+i)^{2} = 2i$

$(1+i)^{4}$ = $(2i)^2$ = $-4$

$(1+i)^{8}  =  (-4)^2 = 16$

similarly,

$(1+i)^{5404}$ = $(1+i)^{4096}$ $(1+i)^{256}$ $(1+i)^{32}$ $(1+i)^{16}$ $(1+i)^{4}$

$(1+i)^{5404}$ = $(256)^{256} (256)^{16} (256)^2 (16)^2 (-4)$

But $(256)^{256} = \infty$

Now how can I solve it? Is my method wrong?

Comment: Your second line is enough to ovtain the answer. Note that $5404/4=1351$.

Comment: **Hint:** $1+i=\sqrt2\exp(i\pi/4)$.

Comment: But again $(-4)^{1351}=infinity !$ @AndréNicolas

Comment: As a typesetting note, use brackets to make sure everything you intend to be raised is actually raised.  Otherwise, only the first character will be put in the superscript.  compare `$a^bcde$` $a^bcde$ to `$a^{bcde}$` $a^{bcde}$

Comment: @shivani Why do you believe $(-4)^{1351}=\infty$? Surely it must be a finite quantity, albeit a large one.

Comment: You should get $-(4^{1351})$. Large negative, but not infinite. However, your calculator may get upset if you ask it to compute this.

Comment: Because when I wrote it in calculator, it showed infinity...!!

Comment: Perhaps you think $256^{256}=\infty$ because you are trying to plug this into a calculator.  This number will be larger than most pocket calculators can handle as it will have $617$ digits, but it is of course a finite number.  It is just larger than the largest number that it can think of.  Calculators are not the end-all be-all of computation.  There comes times where doing math by hand is better than doing math by a calculator since they can be wrong.

Comment: Simple solution, stay away from the calculator, something that is surprisingly often useful to do.

Comment: @shivani i hope you've learned to not EVER trust a calculator. Not ever does it make sense that finite to finite power is infinite. It is illogical

Comment: yes @ZelosMalum its really true... finite to finite power should always be finite and we 'll get a finite number no matter how large it is... I will never forget that...

Comment: Good, then all is learned and well :-)

Answer (score 6):

Use Euler's Formula $$e^{i\theta}=\cos (\theta) + i\sin (\theta)$$
since $1+i=\sqrt{2} (\cos\frac{\pi}{4} +i\sin\frac{\pi}{4})= \sqrt{2} e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}$, so $(1+i)^{5404} =(\sqrt{2} e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}})^{5404}= 2^{2702} e^{i\cdot 1351\pi}= 2^{2702} e^{i\pi}= -2^{2702}$.

Comment: I could not use this identity because the question asked me to do it in any other way...

Answer (score 2):

Here is a general method without using Euler's formula, and formulas for this expansion for any $k$ exponent.

Since we can view multiplication of $i$ as a rotation by 90 degrees, which is
periodic with return to the point of origin after $4$ rotations, we see that $i$ is an element of order 4 (if you've seen a little algebra).

This gives us:

$i^{n}=i$ whenever $n\cong 1 (\mod 4)$

$i^{n}=-1$ whenever $n\cong 2 (\mod 4)$

$i^{n}=-i$ whenever $n\cong 3 (\mod 4)$

$i^{n}=1$ whenever $n\cong 0 (\mod 4)$

Breaking up by these cases, and searching for a pattern from a
few computations you can conjecture
the following formulas:

If $k\cong 1 (\mod 4)$, we have:
    \begin{equation*}
    (1+i)^{k}=(-4)^{\lfloor{k/4}\rfloor}(1+i)
\end{equation*}
  if $k\cong 2 (\mod 4)$, we have:
  \begin{equation*}
  (1+i)^{k}=(-4)^{\lfloor{k/4}\rfloor}2i
  \end{equation*}
  if $k\cong 3 (\mod 4)$, we have:
  \begin{equation*}
  (1+i)^k=(-4)^{\lfloor{k/4}\rfloor}(2i-2)
  \end{equation*}
  if $k\cong 0 (\mod 4)$, we have:
  \begin{equation*}
  (1+i)^k=(-4)^{k/4}
  \end{equation*}

All of which can be proved by induction without too much trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone... Here is the solution as I actually wanted to calculate it. But the main problem was I used calculator instead of my pen!

$(1+i)^{4} = -4$
   &
$(1351)(4) = 5404$

$(1+i)^{5404} = (-4)^{1351}$

$(-4)^{1351} = (-4)^{1350} (-4)$

$(-4)^{1351} = (4)^{675} (4)^{675} (-4)$

$(-4)^{1351} \approx (-2.2) (10)^{812}$

$(1+i)^{5404} \approx (-2.2) (10)^{812}$

Comment: The two last equal signs should be replaced by approximate equal signs.

Comment: Oh yes you are right. I was also thinking, since its not an accurate answer...